# Как сделать электронный измеритель обхвата предплечья

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Нужно сделать приблуду, в которую будет помещаться рука человека и выдаваться значение ее обхвата. Задумка: скорее всего можно использовать несколько датчиков определения расстояния до руки, далее все данные обрабатываются (не знаю как реализовать) и выдается значение обхвата.
Если есть идеи проще - подскажите пожалуйста.
И по способу реализации данной задумки тоже не до конца понимаю

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделать такую фигню, которая будет сжиматься моторчиком. Осталось придумтаь как посчитать пройденный путь ленты

Comment: А чего там думать. Путь на один оборот болта легко измерить.

Comment: главное, чтобы руку не передавило...

Answer (score 0):

Линейный источник подсветки (так, чтобы "зайчик" был в виде полоски), + 3 фотокамеры, расположенных под углом к плоскости освещения, осматривающие руку с разных сторон. Можно заменить 2 камеры на зеркала. Можно ИК, чтобы не пугать пользователя.